# Generate product combinations based on options

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to generate a product combination system based on 2 or more types of options where the final array should look like as displayed in the bellow example. I'm a bit new to this and I have no clue how to do it.
They array keys should start from 1000 and increment from there. The first part of the array contains info about option like option_id name etc and the second part contains some parts of the products in product_option_value.
Any advice or help would be helpful because i'm out of ideas it's very frustrating.

Given an array of options

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [option_id] => 19
            [name] => Colors
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [option_id] => 16
            [name] => Fabric
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [option_id] => 12
            [name] => Size
        )

)
```

And my products array based on color

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 54
            [model] => 01035
            [sku] => 050102/bs
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 57
            [model] => 01038
            [sku] => 050104/b
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 58
            [model] => 01039
            [sku] => 050106/C
        )

)


stdClass Object
(
    [10010] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product_option_id] => 
            [name] => option_name_1
            [value] => option_name_1-option_name_2-option_name_3:::0
            [product_option_value] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [12] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [option_value_id] => 849
                            [product_option_value_id] => 
                            [model] => repellendus nemo ve-050102/bs
                        )

                    [15] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [option_value_id] => 861
                            [product_option_value_id] => 
                            [model] => repellendus nemo ve-050104/b
                        )

                )

        )

    [10011] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product_option_id] => 
            [name] => option_name_1-option_name_2-option_name_3
            [value] => option_name_1-option_name_2-option_name_3:::0-849
            [product_option_value] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [13] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [option_value_id] => 2407
                            [product_option_value_id] => 
                            [model] => repellendus nemo ve-050102/bs-050102/bs
                        )

                )

        )

    [10012] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product_option_id] => 
            [name] => option_name_1-option_name_2-option_name_3
            [value] => option_name_1-option_name_2:::0-849-2407
            [product_option_value] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [14] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [option_value_id] => 2884
                            [product_option_value_id] => 
                            [model] => repellendus nemo ve-050102/bs-050102/bs-050102/bs
                        )

                )

        )

    [10013] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product_option_id] => 
            [name] => option_name_1-option_name_2
            [value] => option_name_1-option_name_2:::0-861
            [product_option_value] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [16] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [option_value_id] => 2407
                            [product_option_value_id] => 
                            [model] => repellendus nemo ve-050104/b-050102/bs
                        )

                )

        )

    [10014] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product_option_id] => 
            [name] => option_name_1-option_name_2-option_name_3
            [value] => option_name_1-option_name_2-option_name_3:::0-861-2407

            [product_option_value] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [17] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [option_value_id] => 2884
                            [model] => repellendus nemo ve-050104/b-050102/bs-050102/bs

                        )

                )

        )
)
```

For the moment I've managed building the "first array that holds the base products" but it doesn't have the name concatenated with the option names

```
            $something = function ($cell, $optionName) {
                $cOption = $this->getOptionByName($optionName, $cell);
                return [
                    "product_option_id" => "",
                    'option_value_id' => 0,
                    'option_val_id' => $cOption['option_value_id'],
                    "name" => $cOption['name'],
                    "value" => $cOption['name'],
                    "option_id" => $cOption['option_id'],

                    "required" => 0,
                    "swatch_image" => 0,
                    "show_first_option_in_list" => "1",
                    "product_option_value" => []
                ];

            };


            $products = [];
            $baseProduct = [];
            $i = 1000;
            for ($c = 4; $c <= 7; $c++) {
                if (!empty($cell[$c])) {
                    $baseProduct = $another($cell[$c], 'Related Colors');
                    $baseProduct['name'] = $baseProduct['name'] .  ':::0';
                    $baseProduct['value'] = $baseProduct['value'] . ':::0';
                    $product = $this->getProductBySku($cell[$c]);
                    $relatedColors[] = $product;
                }
            }
            $baseProduct['product_option_value'] = $relatedColors;
            $products[$i++] = $baseProduct;
```

And this is a visual representation of how on the front should display if the array was build correctly.
[End result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/conpv.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: @ServingQuarantineperiod I've updated with what I have so far.

Comment: What is your expected outcome you want?

Comment: The final output should be that std object. For the moment what i've wrote it generated the base level [10010] => stdClass Object except the concatenation part which I'm not sure how to do it yet.